# Changing EC2 instance type changed my DNS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I had a website in AWS and I tried to increase instance type and I lost connection how can I get the server back again?

Edit:
I am using ReactJs and after changing the AWS instance I cannot connect the website again. I changed the domain in the `config.json` still Network Error I want to know how can I connect again with new DNS?

Comment: Once you've terminated an EC2 instance, it's gone.

Comment: not terminated just changed ec2 type

Comment: If you're using the term "instance type" as it's defined [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) then you can't change an instance's type. If you're using your own definition of the term then you need to explain _exactly_ what you've done. But, as I noted in my close vote reason, instance management is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 3):

If your instance is not attached to an Elastic IP the public DNS endpoint will change if you stop/ start your instance

Comment: To expand on this... An Amazon EC2 instance can be assigned a **Public IP address**. This maps to the **DNS Name**, which contains the IP address. If an Amazon EC2 instance is stopped and started, it _might_ change IP address. This can be avoided by assigning an **Elastic IP address**, which is static and does not change. The best method is to create your own DNS Name in Route 53 (eg `www.mycompany.com`) and create an A-Record that points to the Elastic IP address. This way, it can easily be assigned to another IP address by changing the setting in Route 53.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein thank you for great explanation. I have a question. I already created the Route53 and I was using. Previous I had old DNS address and after the changing I put my new DNS but did not work. If I create an Elastic IP what will be different? Thanks in advance

Comment: You would either be using an A-Record to point to an IP address, or a CNAME-Record to point to a DNS Name. If you assign an Elastic IP address to the instance, you'll need to update the entry to use the new IP address or DNS name. Thereafter, it does not need changing. Please allow time for the update to propagate through the Internet — it will not be instant, especially if your computer has cached a previous result.

Comment: I did not have elastic Ip dress before changing the instance but I set up now and associated to my new instance. I may be did not understand your answer but I cannot make it